# convert the .getMonth to string month in javaScript(convert 0 to jan)

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the month and the array list. var month has the date month number. wanted to convert that number to alphabet.

```
function setDate(data){
    var d = new Date(data.event_details.event_start_date);
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var m = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

    console.log(m);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  function setDate(data){
    var d = new Date(data.event_details.event_start_date); 
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var m =  ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    console.log(m[month]);
  }
```

Use the index to get month

Answer (score 2):

Just access the array of month names using the result of `getMonth()` as the index.

```js
function setDate(data){
  const date = new Date(data.event_details.event_start_date);
  const months = [
    "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
  ];
  console.log(months[date.getMonth()]);
}

setDate({ event_details: { event_start_date: Date.now() } });
```

---

Alternatively, you can ditch the months array altogether and use [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

```js
function setDate(data) {
  const date = new Date(data.event_details.event_start_date);
  const month = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: 'short' });
  
  console.log(month);
}

setDate({ event_details: { event_start_date: Date.now() } });
```

Comment: bravo for the suggested use of built-in language features.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the month by `m[month]`

Comment: Though this could have been a comment, this is actually an answer for this question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Because `Date.getMonth()` returns a number corresponding to the zero-based index of the month, you can simply use that number to access that index in your array (`m`).

```
const monthName = m[month]
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` is the function you need.
Here is the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/pzombade/pen/XOWNdW?editors=1111)

```
function setDate(data){
    var d = new Date(data.event_details.event_start_date);
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var m = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    var monthName=m[month];
    console.log("month= " +monthName );
  }
```